# Is it possible to make input in an Prompt and that to output with this code

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make that the input from `prompt(Username);` prints to the screen with the other code. Check my code out. Note: I am just a begginer so I am asking if this is possible and if you can fix or show me. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing HTML, CSS and JS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
</head>

<body align="center">
    <p id="wname"></p>
    <script>
        alert("You must register first!");
        document.getElementById("sname").innerHTML = prompt("Username");
        document.getElementById("wname").innerHTML = "Welcome, " + document.getElementById("sname");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to make Welcoming to be one code and the Username to show by only itself without Welcome in it. So I made them seperated and trying to + them...

Comment: Maybe add a `.value` to the end of `document.getElementById("sname")` in that last line?

Comment: That didn't worked but I found the right answer, anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a couple of suggestions for your code.

I would first place all of the JavaScript command calls within a function.  This helps your code to be more organized and you could possibly, in the future, call the function at a different time or based on a particular user action, rather than having it just be called as soon as the  element's content is loaded.

For now, however, it seems like you just want the code to be executed when the page is loaded, in which case you can modify your code as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing HTML, CSS and JS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
</head>

<body align="center" onLoad="runCode();">
    <p id="sname"></p>
    <p id="wname"></p>
    <script>
        function runCode(){
            alert("You must register first!");
            var username = prompt("Username");
            document.getElementById("sname").innerHTML = username;
            document.getElementById("wname").innerHTML = "Welcome, " + username;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Additionally, I did not see a paragraph with an ID of `sname` anywhere in your code, so trying to access and change its `innerHTML` will cause errors.  If you would still like the result to be displayed in such an element, then you must create an HTML tag yourself to do so.  I also stored the result of the `prompt()` in the variable `username` for additional organization.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <script>
        alert("You must register first!");
        document.getElementById("sname").innerHTML = prompt("Username");
        document.getElementById("wname").innerHTML = "Welcome, " + 
        document.getElementById("sname").innerHtml;
    </script>
```

Comment: Your code didn't worked but I got the right answer, anyway thanks!